# How can I binding data to Chart?

Tags: charts, livecharts

I want to merge the data to the chart but by somehow it not happening. Can anyone see my problem
(Sorry for my English)

```
 public string[] Labels { get; private set; }
 public int[] Values { get; private set; }
 [ObservableProperty]
 private bool _isLoading;
 private async void LoadHomeDataAsync()
 {
     IsLoading = true;
     await Task.Delay(1000); // Simulated delay

     await using var context = new HotelManagementContext();

     Labels = labels;
     var date = DateTime.Today;
     HomeData.TotalBookingMonday = await GetTotalBookingsForDate(context, -6);
     InitializeCharts();
     IsLoading = false;

 }
 private void InitializeCharts()
 {
     SeriesCollection = new SeriesCollection
         {
             new ColumnSeries
             {
                 Title = "Total booking",
                 Values = new ChartValues<int>
                 {
                     HomeData.TotalBookingMonday,
                     HomeData.TotalBookingTuesday,
                     HomeData.TotalBookingWednesday,
                     HomeData.TotalBookingThursday,
                     HomeData.TotalBookingFriday,
                     HomeData.TotalBookingSaturday,
                     HomeData.TotalBookingSunday
```

I check my value and it can update when i binding in textbox in my xaml. Number are fine too